# Angularjs $resource on localhost not passing data to the controller

Tags: json, spring, angularjs, spring-mvc

I've set up a spring/mongoDB backend that works as a REST Api :

- `GET` on `http://localhost:8080/articles` will get me an array of JSON (all articles)
- `GET` on `http://localhost:8080/articles/:articleId` will get me a single JSON (one article)
- As an example : `GET` on `http://localhost:8080/articles/539edeb08ecdce3f8792084c` gets me : `{"title":"Test","content":"content"}`

On the angularjs side, i've set up a service :

```
angular.module('myApp.services', ['ngResource'])
    .factory('articleService', function ($resource) {
        return $resource('http://localhost:port/articles/539edeb08ecdce3f8792084c',{port:":8080"});
    });
```

And a controller :

```
angular.module('myApp.controllers', ['ngResource'])
  .controller('MyCtrl', ['$scope', 'articleService', function($scope,  articleService) {
    $scope.article = articleService.get();
  }]);
```

My HTML looks like this :

```
<div ng-app="myApp">
    <div ng-controller="MyCtrl">
        {{article}}
    </div>
</div>
```

Now, when I run it, I'm not getting anything on the HTML, but firebug indicates me my request is working :

- [Screenshot of Firebug](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QawNm.jpg)
- `http://i.imgur.com/FSg7Pi2.png` to see the content of the JSON (can't link more than twice)

Also, to make sure i'm not missing anything, i've tried running the same thing on a JSfiddle, requesting from a simple API : [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/3PUxx/4/)

Now, I'm a bit lost. It won't work when i'm requesting my local server, but it works when i'm requesting a remote REST Api. Any idea to help me ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was on Spring's side : by enabling [CORS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-origin_resource_sharing), it has been fixed.

For more information, see [Spring tutorial on CORS](https://spring.io/guides/gs/rest-service-cors/)